# SQL - Storing undefined fields in a table

Tags: sql, database-design

So, I have a few client that want to store user data, the thing is they want to store data without telling me what it is. What I mean is that, they will likely store things like username, first name, last name and email, but then there are a myriad of other things that are no defined and that can change.

So with that in mind, I want to create a table that can handle that data. I was thinking of setting up a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Details](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnValue] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Details] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Is this the best way to store this data, or am I making a mistake?

Please help me before I go ahead and create this table! :D

Comment: Sigh. Key-Value pairs in a relational DB. You could do it like that. I wouldn't. While your at it, why not a single table with everything in it?

Comment: Any possible solution?

Comment: Yeah. Find out what needs to be stored.

Comment: That is not viable. It will always change.

Comment: Do me a favour and don't reply to posts if you have nothing good to add.

Comment: Do me a favour. Don't ask redundant questions.

Comment: The question is not redundant, as I have explained it is a requirement.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185446/better-way-of-storing-key-value-pairs-in-the-database

Comment: well done! You searched!

Comment: What database are you using? E.g. Postgresql has a hstore datatype that stores key/value pairs that might do what you need.

Comment: I can use any database, I have just been looking at MondoDb although not sure how easy that is to work with in C# :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make clear to your clients that fields the database knows about, like a user number, name, and address can be searched fast, checked for consistency, and even be used for program control (such as some users see or can do what others cannot), whereas "undefined data" will not.

Then find out, if they really need single entities. Then the name/value approach is exactly the way to go. Maybe, however, it suffices to store one note per user, where they enter all their comments, memos, etc., i.e. just one text to hold all "undefined data". If possible this would be a better approach.